# how to build a 'page track' in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 6 pages built in SSRS in a break down sequence:

A->B->C->D->E->F

I wonder is there a way to build a 'page track' something like displaying 'A->B->C->D->E->F' on the top of each page

for example:

when on page B, it displays: A->B
when on page E, it displays: A->B->C->D->E

It is a kind of navigation, which can let the user know which level the current page is and user can jump to any of the page by clicking the page name.

Thanks

ry

Comment: How do your users access the report? Is it a single report with manual page breaks?

Comment: Can your users not see the standard toolbar that shows the page number and offers the ability to jump to any by typing the page number in?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify pages by using `PageNumber` global variable. `PageNumber` is only accessible from `Page Header` and `Page Footer`, so you have to add a Page Header/Page Footer via `Report` in menu bar.

Then place a textbox inside it with the following expression:

```
=Switch(
Globals!PageNumber=1,"Page Track: A",
Globals!PageNumber=2,"Page Track: A -> B",
Globals!PageNumber=3,"Page Track: A -> B -> C",
Globals!PageNumber=4,"Page Track: A -> B -> C -> D",
Globals!PageNumber=5,"Page Track: A -> B -> C -> D -> E",
Globals!PageNumber=5,"Page Track: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F"
)
```

Regarding to the navigation option that lets your user jump between pages. I think it is possible by using action and bookmark properties in a chart/tablix/textbox in every page.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks, however i wish that for 'A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F', each of node is hyperlinkable

Comment: @ryan. You can't use hyperlink to go to another page, but you can go to a specific chart/tablix in a page. I mean if you have a chart in third page you can jump to that page by link the chart in your hyperlink property.